# "Maximum Lines in a Branch" in config file

Tags: phpmyadmin, config

How can I set the "Maximum Lines in a Branch" Navigation Panel setting into the config file? I can't find it in the documentation, and I have to reset this every time phpMyAdmin loses it's session info. The v4.0.5 release has really made my life miserable with the changes in defaults (or new features with defaults I don't like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're referring to MaxNavigationItems. Try version 4.0.6, there have been improvements in the navigation panel.

Comment: Thanks, I'm renting a dedicated server and it's set up to autoinstall updates, but I don't know what triggers them. I've seen the "4.0.6 available" note for the last couple of days or so, so I'm hoping it makes life easier than the last one did. I've have to edit the config file for skin preference for some time, now I have several more configs to keep updated, I suppose. The Config Storage option looks too complicated for me. I know just enough linux and sever stuff as I'm forced to learn (just one of many, many skills that I have to learn to get the job done).

Comment: Did you try to increase the MaxNavigationItems setting in config.inc.php? If so and it helped, please mark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: It seems to have worked. I can see now that if we make a change in the Settings area, the name of the config option is shown in the hover text.